# How to get string values in the object with nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

When I run my code and it returns `{"pass": "123"}`. how to get "`123`" please help me

```js
    app.post("/",urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
        pool.connect(function(err,client,done){
            client.query("select password from account where user='"+req.body.textUser+"'",function(err,result){
                var password = result.rows[0];
                res.send(password);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password` is a dictionary so if you want just the value of pass then you can do this: `res.send(password.pass);`